# Why function call in view trigger onChanges multiple times but not prop variable -- Angular

Tags: angular, onchange

I have really simple component which render child component with prop.
I tried to replicate the issue [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-duplicate-function-view) (Check console, it console twice while expected once)

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  list = [1];
  testVar = this.testFunc();


  testFunc() {
    return {
      name: "Dipak"
    };
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of list; index as i">
  <child [myProp]="testFunc()"> </child>
</ng-container>
```

`child.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: ` I am child`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input() myProp; 
  ngOnChanges (change) {
    console.log(" Changes --- > ", change)
  }
}
```

If I pass prop with component variable i.e `testVar` onChanges in child component call only once. But if I called function i.e `testFunc()`for prop value in parent view onChanges getting called multiple time.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-duplicate-function-view) (Check console)

In my actual application its getting called more than 20 times. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function in the template, thus it will fire on each change detection. Try putting an input, and type in the field, and you will see that it fires more times.
Calling functions in the template is discouraged, as it's called on each change detection, and in worst case it can cause what seems to be an infinite loop, even though it's not, it's just change detection happening.

Here's your modified stackblitz with the input. Type in and see console: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-duplicate-function-view-albby4?file=src/app/child.component.ts)

The solution is to use a variable in the template instead of function, as you have by testing already established.

*As a further thing worth mentioning (not related to current question): If you are depending on `ngOnChanges` to do something with the variable, we need to remember that if you are only changing a property, `ngOnChanges` will not fire. It only fires if the reference changing, as it is doing in your code now.*